# Estoy aprendiendo en javascript y al usar xxxx.includes() me salta la alerta de que no es una función, aparte al agregarlo el codigo no funciona bien

Tags: javascript, html, web

Es un código mal optimizado y muy básico pues recién estoy aprendiendo, pero me funcionaba bastante bien hasta que agregué `validacion = resultado.includes(".");` para así al realizar una operación que sea exacta y no me de un resultado como 4.00 porque lo veo feo y prefiero que sea exacto.
Me da un error en la consola de google:
`Uncaught TypeError: resultado.includes is not a function at app.js:72:28`
¿Que tendría que corregir para que me funcione o como debería reestructurar el código para que sea funcional y que al obtener numero exactos no me de un 4.00, pero que cuando sea inexacto si se vean por lo menos 2 decimales.

```
else if(operacion == 6){
let numero1 = prompt("¿A que numero le deseas sacar su raiz cúbica?");
resultado = raizCúbica(numero1);
validacion = resultado.includes(".");
if(validacion == false){
    document.write(`El resultado de tu operación es ${resultado}`);
}else{
    resultadon = resultado.toFixed(2);
    document.write(`El resultado de tu operación es ${resultadon}`);
}
```

}

Comment: Al codigo le faltan cosas, por favor incluye tambien la funcion `raizCubica`, ademas recuerda que no es una buena practica usar caracteres que no esten en el alfabeto ingles ya sea para declarar variables o funciones, lo maz probable es que raiz cubica te este devolviendo algo que efectivamente no posee ese metodo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente el resultado del llamado de la función de `raizCubica` retorna un tipo numérico y la función `includes` no se encuentra disponible en este tipo de dato.

Lo que puedes hacer es hacer un casting o conversión de tipo de dato a uno que si tiene accesible esta propiedad, este es una cadena de caracteres o `string`, para convertirlo podrías hacerlo siguiente:

```js
let numero1 = prompt("¿A que numero le deseas sacar su raiz cúbica?");
resultado = raizCúbica(numero1);
validacion = resultado.toString().includes(".");
```

Nota que la conversión se realizó a través de llamar previamente la función `toString()` en la variable